# Как хранить ссылочные данные

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Что бы было проще, объясню на примере чатов. Есть пользовать П1, и есть пользователь П2, они между собой ведут беседу, естественно данные об их беседе храняться в БД, но встал вопрос, как хранить сообщения? И все об сообщении?

К примеру, User1 которые имеет в себе список сообщения Message1, Message2, как этот список хранить в БД? Если же каждое сообщения отвечает за текст, дату отправки/получения, флаг было ли прочитано, и многое другое.

Вижу только один выход, хранить все в каком-то формате, к примеру JSON, а потом хранить в конкретном поле данные об всех сообщениях со всеми пользователями.

Из плюсов:

- Легко реализуемо
- Легкий доступ

Из минусов:

- Каждый раз парсить из этого формата что бы добавить/получить данные слишком долго.
- Ресурсоемко, при доставании хранить все в ОЗУ (парсить).

К тому же не представляю как будет хранить между разными пользователям, к примеру П1 - П2, П1 - П3, П1 - П4, разве что хранить все в том же поле, но тогда  все еще хуже.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть *автор сообщения*, есть *получатель сообщения*. Они имеют каждый свой ID. Даже группа - имеет свой ID, но может выступать только *получателем сообщения*.

Исходя из этого и получаем структуру таблицы сообщений:

- ID автора;
- ID получателя;
- содержимое;
- timestamp создания сообщения;
- признак доставки;
- признак прочтения;
- "многое другое".

Для выборки использовать запрос типа

```sql
SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE
   author_id IN (<ID автора>, <ID получателя>) AND
   recipient_id IN (<ID автора>, <ID получателя>)
ORDER BY created_at
```

Все классически укладывается в реляционную структуру. Так и не понял, в чем у Вас загвоздка-то вышла?

Comment: Могу лишь добавить, что признаком доставки и прочтения могут быть дата доставки и дата прочтения.

Comment: то есть, для каждого сообщения своя строка? Не много ли, ведь для 100 друзей, при 100 сообщениях нужно будет 495к строк, как по мне, это очень затратно, или нет?

Comment: А какая разница? Объем хранения ведь все равно одинаковый, что совой об пень, что пнем об сову - а хранить надо. Только при хранении в отдельной таблице в базе за счет правильно составленных индексов можно добиться **очень** быстрой выборки вместо того, чтобы осуществлять "закат солнца вручную", парся JSON кодом на PHP.

Comment: [СУБД — ком­плекс про­грамм, по­зво­ляю­щих соз­дать ба­зу дан­ных (БД) и ма­ни­пу­ли­ро­вать дан­ны­ми (встав­лять, об­нов­лять, уда­лять и вы­би­рать). Система обес­пе­чи­ва­ет безо­пас­ность, на­дёж­ность хра­не­ния и це­ло­ст­ность дан­ных...](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) Если есть желание посоревноваться с многолетним опытом коллективов профессиональных разработчиков - удачи!